# Migrated 2013 workflows are not working in new server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, app-step

We had our SP 2013 applications in old server, so we migrated to new server with content DB approach. Now I see the 2013 designer workflows are having problem in executing the actions inside APP Step.I tried below steps to resolve but no luck.

Deactivated and reactivated 'Workflow Can use app permission' feature.Provided the Full control permission to Workflow app over appinv.aspx. Republished the WFs .

But If I create new test workflows inside in the site having App steps. Then it executes fine. Only the existing migrated WFs are having problem.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to republish Workflows in the new site. WF2013 is not migrating with SP content DB they have their own DBs. You can either republish the workflows or try WF Scope Restore to new farm.

Answer (score 0):

For workflow 2010, it is integrated with SharePoint Server and stored in content database. So you can automatically restore it by restoring the content database.

For workflow 2013, it requires Workflow Manager and must be installed separately and then configured to work with your SharePoint Server. SO you need to migrate the workflow manager.